# Integrate Mpesa API with google forms

Tags: google-apps-script, mpesa

I want to integrate Mpesa API to a google form. 
Users using the form to pay, let us say for registration Fee

Comment: Can you link m to the API.. well if it's public....

Comment: http://www.safaricom.co.ke/business/sme/m-pesa-payment-solutions/m-pesa-api

Comment: http://www.safaricom.co.ke/images/Downloads/Resources_Downloads/M-PESA_API_Guide_download.zip

Comment: Never saw an API written in such a way.. please share your findings when you resolve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You now use M-Pesa RESTful APIs accessible through Safaricom's [developer portal](https://developer.safaricom.co.ke). The [documentation](https://developer.safaricom.co.ke/docs) has sample codes in the major programming languages - Python, JavaScript/NodeJS, Java, Ruby.

You can now consume the M-Pesa RESTful APIs with Google Apps Script like you would any other RESTful APIs.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. The JSON Requests is now a God send

Comment: You are most welcome. Should you have any queries about the M-Pesa APIs, address them to apifeedback@safaricom.co.ke.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is possible by using Apps Script to create a google form.

> **Forms Service**
>
> This service allows scripts to create, access, and modify Google Forms.

Here is a sample code for creating a google form using Apps Scripts.

```
// Create a new form, then add a checkbox question, a multiple choice question,
// a page break, then a date question and a grid of questions.
var form = FormApp.create('New Form');
var item = form.addCheckboxItem();
item.setTitle('What condiments would you like on your hot dog?');
item.setChoices([
        item.createChoice('Ketchup'),
        item.createChoice('Mustard'),
        item.createChoice('Relish')
    ]);
form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
    .setTitle('Do you prefer cats or dogs?')
    .setChoiceValues(['Cats','Dogs'])
    .showOtherOption(true);
form.addPageBreakItem()
    .setTitle('Getting to know you');
form.addDateItem()
    .setTitle('When were you born?');
form.addGridItem()
    .setTitle('Rate your interests')
    .setRows(['Cars', 'Computers', 'Celebrities'])
    .setColumns(['Boring', 'So-so', 'Interesting']);
Logger.log('Published URL: ' + form.getPublishedUrl());
Logger.log('Editor URL: ' + form.getEditUrl());
```

Then you can integrate the third party API in the Apps Scripts.

> **External APIs**
>
> Google Apps Script can interact with APIs from all over the web. This guide shows how to work with different types of APIs in your scripts.
>
> Dozens of Google APIs are available in Apps Script, either as [built-in services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/) or [advanced services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced). If you want to use a Google (or non-Google) API that isn't available as an Apps Script service, you can connect to the API's public HTTP interface through the [URL Fetch service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch).
>
> The following example makes a request to the YouTube API and returns a feed of videos that match the query `skateboarding dog`.

```
var url = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?'
    + 'q=skateboarding+dog'
    + '&start-index=21'
    + '&max-results=10'
    + '&v=2';
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
Logger.log(response);
```

Similarly, the following example uploads a video to YouTube. Also using `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`

```
var payload = 'XXXXX'; // Replace with raw video data.
var headers = {
    'GData-Version': '2',
    'Slug': 'dog-skateboarding.mpeg'
    // Add any other required parameters for the YouTube API.
};
var url = 'https://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads';
var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'headers': headers,
    'payload': payload
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check my answer on a similar question to yours here: [Intergrating Mobile Money like Mpesa and AirtelMoney with Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40433067/intergrating-mobile-money-like-mpesa-and-airtelmoney-with-android-app/40434323#40434323)

Explore the possibbility of developing an android app with a custome made Mpesa api to help you store Mpesa messages online and optimize that information for use on Google Forms